# Way to track files/folders being moved in TFS

Tags: tfs

At some point in the past few weeks, one of our folders in TFS disappeared. I've tried having it display deleted files, and it's not there. I've tried using the folder history compare tool to walk back in time, and the folder doesn't show up.

I suspect that the folder may have been moved to a different area of the source tree. Does TFS track if/when a file or folder is moved in a manner that can be queried?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find the current location of the folder:

```
tf dir $/*MyFolder* /recursive /server:http://TFSServer:8080
```

You may need to play with the $/*MyFolder* part a bit. Maybe try some variations like $/*MyFolder, $/MyFolder, etc.